# Magento 2 and Authorize.net MD5 - What does this mean for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

https://developer.authorize.net/support/hash_upgrade/?utm_campaign=19Q2%20MD5%20Hash%20EOL%20Partner&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua

Might anyone be able to shed some light on what this means for Magento 2 sites using Authorize? I've had weirdly little success finding any discussion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find much more discussion on it, but others have realized the issue as well:
https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/127

Answer (score 1):

The end of life for MD5 Hash will be done in two phases:

Phase 1 - Remove ability to configured/update MD5 Hash setting in the Merchant Interface. This feature will be removed in the coming weeks by end of January 2019/early February 2019. **This change has no impact to the API response, that will be done in Phase 2.**

Phase 2 - Stop sending the MD5 Hash data element in the API response. The date for this change will be announced at a later time but is expected in the next 2-3 months.

For more details check this https://support.authorize.net/s/article/MD5-Hash-End-of-Life-Signature-Key-Replacement

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is getting disabled completely and it means Magento 2 will most likely need an upgrade to remain compatible. Authorize.net has stated that the existing hashes will not be immediately killed when setting the MD5 is removed.

Comment: This was the previous process for using the transHash method, does this mean the process hasn't changed? From the docs it seems we will need to setup a Signature Key and use a new process for verifying the hash value. 
See https://developer.authorize.net/support/hash_upgrade/?utm_campaign=19Q2%20MD5%20Hash%20EOL%20Partner&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua

Comment: I was specifically referring to the article linked. Md5 Hash support is being removed after this month, so how will this be handled in Magento 2 starting February 2019

Comment: I have just now seen the news about this but nothing from Magento devs yet.

Comment: The wording from Auth.Net indicates the functionality in the merchant settings will be removed, but the MD5 hash of whatever code was set will still remain available until some future announcement.

Comment: Authorize.net has listed March 14, 2019 as the date the MD5 field will stop being populated:

https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/MD5-Hash-Removal-Disablement-March-14-2019/m-p/65585#M219

Comment: The problem is their patch doesn't seem to work - or at least a number of people including myself are unable to get it to work

Comment: @Scott - I have applied the signature key update patch to Magento 1 and Magento 2 with success. It does work fine.